# Will there be any memory issues if Unity and Ninject Dependency injection used together in the same solution?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ninject, unity-container

I have a solution with several class library projects and a WCF web service project already in it. The dependency Injection is handled in Unity 2.1 where in web config file of the WCF project I have registered my new class library project as below.

```
<container name="unityDI">
<register type="INewProcess" mapTo="NewProcess"/>
<register type="ISomeService" mapTo="SomeService">
        <constructor>
            <param name="newProcess" type="INewProcess" />
            <param name="Service1" type="IService1" />
            <param name="repository1" type="IRepository1" />
        </constructor>
  </register>
```

In the class library project I added to this solution NewProcess class is where the client will consume the library.

That is the class where I do initiate the dependency handling process to handle the dependencies within the class library. this library implements the strategy pattern for handling validations based on different workflows and few other helper classes which used implement different utilities for this validation.

Below is the code I have in NewProcess class

```
public class NewProcess : INewProcess
{
    private readonly IKernel _kernel = new StandardKernel(new NewProcessValidationsLibraryNinjectModule());

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public Tuple<string, IDictionary<string, string>> DetermineCandidate(string val1, string val2, string val3)
    {
        var newValidationObjectFactory = _kernel.Get<INewValidationObjectFactory>();
        return newValidationObjectFactory.DetermineValidationStrategy(val1, val2, val3);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public NewStatusObject GetSomeReceivedStatus(NewStatusObject newStatusObject)
    {
        var statusReceiveStatusChecker = _kernel.Get<IStatusReceiveStatusChecker>();
        return statusReceiveStatusChecker.GetNewReceiveStatus(newStatusObject);
    }
}
```

And in the NewProcessValidationsLibraryNinjectModule i have the below code

```
public class NewProcessValidationsLibraryNinjectModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Kernel.Bind(x => x.FromThisAssembly().SelectAllClasses().BindAllInterfaces());
    }
}
```

Can someone please let me know will there be any memory leak related issues while using both Unity and Ninject at the same time as above? Or is this the correct way of using both Unity and Ninject within the same solution? Will the new up of StandardKernel end up in memory issues?

Comment: Measure, measure, measure.

Comment: @Steven what do you mean?

Comment: What I mean is that _you_ should measure and profile whether or not memory usage is within reasonable boundaries and whether or not there are any memory issues.

Comment: Are you really planning to instantiate a kernel and its modules each time you instantiate a `NewProcess` ? This seems like a bad idea. The design seems awkward : Which component instantiates `NewProcess`as an `IProcess` ?`NewProcess` should not be aware of Ninject, Kernel, Module or Dependency Resolution.

Comment: The WCF Web services project instantiates NewProcess as INewProcess using unity. If my Newprocess is the starting point of a class library where else I should create the Kernel to handle the dependancies within the class library project. I need this library to be able to use in other solutions as well irrespective of the DI container the consumer is using.

Answer (score 0):

I had a lengthy look at the comments I received and did some testing at run time and found that the way I have implemented the DI in my library it was loading and unloading the Ninject Kernel on request basis which is not the way you want your DI container to work. 
It should load all the dependencies when you load it first time.

To resolve this issue I opt to use Unity across my solution. Apparently this move made the library calls faster and I do not have to worry about using 2 different DI containers in the same solution and complexities it can bring to your solution.